# Dynamic SPA routes for statically generated Nuxt app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt project that is fully statically generated. But one part of this is pretty dynamic. Let's say it is `items` page and `items/:id` pages. Where on the items page we render the list of items as links to each `items/:id` page.

I would like to opt-out of a static generation for those 2 pages. For now, I used the following changes to the `nuxt.config.js`:

```
export default {
  target: 'static',
  router: {
    extendRoutes (routes, resolve) {
      routes.push({
        name: 'items',
        path: '/items/*',
        component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/items/_slug.vue')
      })
    }
  },
  generate: { exclude: [/^\/items/], fallback: '404.html' }
```

This works nicely when I do `nuxt generate` & `nuxt start` but only for navigation within the website. When I go directly to let's say `/items/42` I get `404` rendered.

How should I adjust configuration or deployment to make it work?

Comment: I'm not sure that you need to [extend the routes](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-router/#extendroutes) of Nuxt since it will do it for you with the crawler. Do you use `ssr: true` or not? Did you read this one? Also, do you have a [repro]?

Comment: We have default value there `ssr: true`. Good point about minimal reproducible example. I will prepare that.